# Solr DIH invalid fetch size

Tags: java, database, ms-access, solr

When I try to access my access db with solr DIH it gives me an error:

```
    java.sql.SQLException: Invalid Fetch Size
```

My configuration and requesthandler and dataconfig. Im using a 2007 access db from a file. I already changed my java version to 32bit to communicate with the 32bit driver. So I don't think its related to that.

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" 
              driver="sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"
              url="jdbc:odbc:test"
              batchSize="-1"
                convertType="true"/>
  <document>
    <entity name="id" 
            query="select ID from myTest">
    </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>

  <requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

Comment: batchSize="-1" i think would be it. Try changing it to "1" because a -1 sets it to fetch 500 rows in one batch per default and some drivers can't handle that.

Comment: I've set it to 0 and it seems to work ok for now. But I'm getting other errors after adding around 60000 docs it stopts :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting your `batchSize="-1"` to `batchSize="1"` or `0`.
Setting the batchSize to -1 is the default value and thusly the DIH sets it to the default of 500 and some drivers can't handle that.

You can read more here [DIH FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandlerFaq)

As to your getting some other error, can you please post what that error is?

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]Invalid transaction state. I only got it after adding around 60000 documents.

Comment: After adding or reading? If you're reading from the MS Access file you have encountered some form of lock on the transaction so try closing it inbetween reads.

Comment: I had to set a non-0 batch size (e.g. 100), my setup wouldn't recognize `-1` or `0`.