# XPages JDBC connected to MS ACCESS DB, issue showing data in ViewPanel

Tags: ms-access, jdbc, xpages

I am trying to connect XPagesJDBC.nsf to a simple MS Access database, 
it connects Successfully and i am able to perform the @JdbcInsert , Update, Delete. also able to execute SQL Query operations.

But i am facing an issue while trying to showing data in  ViewPanel control with JDBC Query datasource type.

It give bellow error

```
Error while reading the relational data
Invalid Fetch Size
```

and a long StackTrace, i am copying some part of stack trace bellow;

I think this error is specific to MS Access, because i could find some successful implementation with other RDBMS also it work fine with "durby" at my end.

```
 com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:840)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx._renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1317)
com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1255)
com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doRender(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:641)
com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:320)
com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:335)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:103)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:120)
com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.render(FacesControllerImpl.java:264)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:248)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:200)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:137)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1267)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:847)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1251)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:598)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:421)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:341)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:297)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid Fetch Size
    sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.setFetchSize(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:838)
    sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.setFetchSize(JdbcOdbcResultSet.java:2987)
    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.jdbc.model.JdbcDataBlockAccessor.loadBlock(JdbcDataBlockAccessor.java:389)
    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.model.DataBlockAccessor.findBlockByIndex(DataBlockAccessor.java:344)
    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.model.DataBlockAccessor.prefetchData(DataBlockAccessor.java:292)
    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.model.DataAccessorModel.getRowCount(DataAccessorModel.java:93)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIPager$PagerState.<init>(UIPager.java:76)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIPager$PagerState.<init>(UIPager.java:71)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIPager.createPagerState(UIPager.java:540)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.XPagerRenderer.encodeChildren(XPagerRenderer.java:67)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:162)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:979)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:842)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.ViewPanelRenderer.processPagerCell(ViewPanelRenderer.java:656)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.ViewPanelRenderer.encodeBegin(ViewPanelRenderer.java:354)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeBegin(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:146)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:956)
    javax.faces.component.UIData.encodeBegin(UIData.java:788)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataEx.encodeBegin(UIDataEx.java:413)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewPanel.encodeBegin(UIViewPanel.java:288)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:840)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
```

myconnection.jdbc file ; ext_db is a DSN

```
<jdbc>
    <driver>sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver</driver>
    <url>jdbc:odbc:ext_db</url>
    <user>xxx</user>
    <password>xxx</password>
</jdbc>
```

Answer (score 1):

The tongue-in-cheek-answer: get a database :-)
The problem seems to be [well known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13398713/solr-dih-invalid-fetch-size) and [plagues others](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/TEIID-1292?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel&_sscc=t) too to [quite some extend](https://www.google.com/search?q=MS+Access+Java+Invalid+Fetch+Size). The batch-size parameter (first link) might work. You also could revisit your requirements. Would DECS do the trick?

Comment: hi stev, thanks for that update, i tried the step with a extra tag <batchSize> in my .jdbc file but it does not work. may be this step has to be done in the actual java implementation ? Also it is just a learning project and Access was the easy db available for me other than open-source mySQL, for which i guess it works fine.

Comment: Use mySQL or OrientDB or Derby -- quickly installed and a whole world of new troubles ;-)

Comment: Hi. Just wondering how important it is to make that JDBC-ODBC bridge configuration with MS Access involved workable? And were you able to use some MySQL for that instead as what Stephan has already proposed?