# (XPages)Can use Javascript to connect ODBC data to show on XPages?

Tags: javascript, odbc, xpages, lotus-notes

I have some data stored in ODBC, and those data look like this:

[image]

Does anyone use calculated fields or other functions to display ODBC data in XPages?

I need to display the data stored in ODBC in XPages, and then write other data to save back to ODBC.

---

Originally used ASP to write this function, the writing method is as follows:

```
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.open b8_dsn

SQL = "SELECT PONUM as PONUM,COMP_NAME as Company,CASENAME AS Case_name,PRICE as Price" 
SQL = SQL & " FROM CB4_AUCTION"
Set rs = conn.Execute(SQL)
```

Comment: Of course you might want to explore a code free option. The DECS service can connect Notes databases to RDBMS and keep the data in sync. Some reading about it:
https://www.wissel.net/blog/2009/09/domino-and-rdbms.html
https://www.wissel.net/blog/2008/11/advanced-decs-usage.html

Answer (score 1):

Your best course of action is to encapsulate the ODBC (actually more JDBC) data into a managed bean. Design one property of the bean to be like

```
  public List<SomeData> getRows();
```

and you can use `beanName.rows` directly in a repeat control as data source.
Design the `SomeData` as Java bean (which is fancy for: having getSomeValue(), setSomeValue(...) pairs of methods, so you can directly bind them to a form using `beanInstanceName.someValue` (where *beanInstanceName* is the variable name of your repeat control)

You can read about bean data binding here:
https://wissel.net/blog/2011/01/binding-controls-to-managed-beans.html

And how to save yourself some headache by creating and testing your bean outside of XPages first here:
https://wissel.net/blog/2013/06/managed-beans-xpages-and-testability.html

You want to use [the extension library](https://extlib.openntf.org/), which comes with ODBC/JDBC stuff and check related questions:

- [How do I access SQL from XPages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026052/how-do-i-access-sql-from-xpages/9101473)
- [XPages JDBC connected to MS ACCESS DB, issue showing data in ViewPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137370/xpages-jdbc-connected-to-ms-access-db-issue-showing-data-in-viewpanel)

Let us know what worked for you!